# Basic subtraction query statement

Tags: mysql

I stuck. What I want to do is to subtract the value of each client INVOICE TOTAL minus the average value named as INVOICES AVERAGE to know the difference value.

If I remove the  **invoice_total - invoices_average AS 'differences'** statement the query runs perfect.

```
SELECT
        client_id,
        invoice_id,
        invoice_total,
        AVG(invoice_total) AS 'invoices_average',
        invoice_total - invoices_average AS 'differences'
FROM invoices
GROUP BY invoice_id
```

Comment: `invoice_total - AVG(invoice_total) AS differences`, you cannot use the alias there

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I tried that. And all I retrieve are zeros in the whole 'difference' column

Comment: The column alias `invoices_average` does not exist until the query has been executed, so it cannot be used as part of the query itself.  It wouldn't make any sense even if your quesry executed, because the AVG()` of that row is going to be the same amount as `invoice_total`, which means you'll always get `0`. I believe you want to get the average of the entire column (aggregated) in order to find out how the current row compares to the average of that column, right? Then that's what you need to be asking how to do, and you should provide sample data and the output you want to get from it.

Comment: Hi @davy please use subquery where you'll calculate the difference.

Comment: add some sample data and desired results for that sample data.  you should not be mixing columns for individual invoices rows and the AVG that is for all rows for a given invoice_id (and if you try, you will get inconsistent results, or in recent versions with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY on by default, an error), but it isn't clear to me what you actually want

Comment: SELECT
  client_id,
        invoice_id,
        invoice_total, 
(
  SELECT
    AVG(invoice_total)
  FROM invoices
)  AS "invoices_average",
        
  invoice_total - (SELECT invoices_average) AS 'differences'

FROM invoices

GROUP BY invoice_id

Comment: Hi @davy is invoice_total for an invoice_id along with client_id is cummulative total?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did, and got the result

```
SELECT 
    client_id, 
    invoice_id,
    invoice_total,
    (
        SELECT
                AVG(invoice_total)
        FROM invoices
    ) AS "invoices_average",         
    invoice_total - (SELECT invoices_average) AS 'differences'             
    FROM invoices                
    GROUP BY invoice_id
```

[image]